# Programmatically set a picture as a powerpoint background through file embedded on an excel template

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm generating a PPT presentation through vba in excel, everything is working just fine except that Im being asked to automatically set background of the power point (which it wouldn't be much a  problem) but this will be done with a picture that is actually embedded on the macro, so I dont have physical path to reference the picture, plus the excel is generated on the fly according to the user inputs.

so.. has anyone achieved this : Programmatically set a slide backrground from vba excel with a picture that is embedded on a sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but if the image being shown is changing on the fly according to user input, then it's not an actual image file, right?

Comment: @Issun: what i understand is the file won't change *on the fly* but will be set by a user input through Excel vba, so that Rafael will have the info in a var when creating his PPT presentation

Comment: Actually the Excel file will be generated through WebFocus which is a reporting tool that we use at work, the content within the excel book dinamically changes according some selections made on an user interface, the picture is always the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a way to set the background directly from a picture in memory, what about copy/pasting the picture from Excel into the Slide Master(s) in your PPT presentation then sending them to the back so they sit behind everything.  The effect would be nearly identical from the user's point of view, I think.

Comment: That sounds like worth to try! I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 4):

As far as i understand, you want to **set the background of the slides in vba** (it doesn't matter it is called from Excel).

Let's assume you have the path in a var:

```
Dim osld As Slide
Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range  'every slides of the presentation
'This is important in some cases
osld.FollowMasterBackground = False
With osld.Background.Fill
  .UserPicture <string var containing path to image>
End With
End Sub
```

You will also have to adapt `ActivePresentation` with the PPT object you built from your previous code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this is not what I want to do since I don't have the path of the image. The picture is stored on a spreadsheet of the book that generates the presentation.

Comment: so, maybe you could save the image from the generated Excel. Sounds a little tricky for what it's worth.

Comment: do you mean like save the file on the users machine the use that path to add it to the ppt?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant. This is not the cleanest solution i've ever seen but that not that bad.

Comment: or else, you can copy-paste it but you won't be able to set it to the background but you can set it in the master slides as Steve suggested

Comment: I think both ideas are good, I'll play with both and let you guys know which one worked the best. Thanks!

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it suits my needs very well, since I do have a path to my image. Setting a background is preferable to copy/pasting the image because the recipient shouldn't be able to interact with the background.